# Is there any way to link two or more different classes into one class (and later use on a vector)?

Tags: c++, class, vector

So I am basically trying to link two different classes and use both in the same vector. 
For example, if I have one class called "CPlayer" and another one called "CEnemy" where they have different elements but the same principle, how do I link it possibly into a class named "CEntity"? I want to avoid messy and hard code.

Comment: You may want to review chapters on *inheritance* and *polymorphism* in your favorite C++ textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@IgorTandetnik is right, ***polymorphism*** is the solution. I have posted a descriptive snippet here to guide your thoughts as you learn this interesting topic.

```
emum entity_type_enum { PLAYER, ENEMY };

struct CEntity
{
  CEntity(void) { /**/ }
  virtual ~CEntity(void) { /**/ }
  virtual entity_type_enum id(void) = 0;
};

struct CPlayer : public CEntity
{
  CPlayer(void) { /**/ }
  virtual ~CPlayer(void) { /**/ }
  entity_type_enum id(void) { return PLAYER; }
};

struct CEnemy : public CEntity
{
  CEnemy(void) { /**/ }
  virtual ~CEnemy(void) { /**/ }
  entity_type_enum id(void) { return ENEMY; }
};

std::vector<CEntity*> objects;

objects.push_back(new CEnemy());
objects.push_back(new CPlayer());
```

To get actual player or enemy

```
auto *ptr = objects[0];

if (ptr->id() == ENEMY)
{
  auto *E = dynamic_cast<CEnemy*>(ptr);
  // do something with enemy...
}

if (ptr->id() == PLAYER)
{
  auto *P = dynamic_cast<CPlayer*>(ptr);
  // do something with player...
}
```

And to clean up

```
for (auto *ptr : objects) delete ptr;
objects.clear();
```

Comment: Another person answered below, but all in all I find your answer to be a bit better (easier and reliable). Thank you sincerely. :)

Comment: @HolyRandom Thanks for asking the question ..I'm glad we could help.

Answer (score 1):

[Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) has given you basically a good advice. But here's a simple solution that does not involve inheritence and hence, dynamic casting. In case you need to store your `Entities` without polymorphism, there are a couple solutions:

**Use `std::variant` (requires C++17):**

```
#include <variant>

class CPlayer 
{
    // impl
};
class CEnemy 
{
    // impl
};

using RefCPlayer = std::reference_wrapper<CPlayer>;
using RefCEnemy = std::reference_wrapper<CEnemy>;
using EntityWrapper = std::variant<RefCPlayer, RefCEnemy>;

void deduce(EntityWrapper e)
{
    switch (e.index())
    {
    case 0:
        std::cout << "This is a CPlayer entity" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 1:
        std::cout << "This is a CEnemy entity" << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    CPlayer p1;
    CEnemy e1;

    std::vector<EntityWrapper> entities;
    entities.emplace_back(RefCPlayer(p1));
    entities.emplace_back(RefCEnemy(e1));

    EntityWrapper w1 = entities[0],
        w2 = entities[1];
    deduce(w1);
    deduce(w2);
}
```

`std::variant::index`

> Returns the zero-based index of the alternative that is currently held by the variant.

**Another way** is to use a vector of `std::pair<enum Entity, std::any>`.

If the variant is valueless_by_exception, returns variant_npos.

Comment: 4 years late haha but I'm not sure how your answer could've helped. At the time I didn't know what polymorphism was, but I did know how to make a state-machine like you did here (well, sort of). Hence I said "I want to avoid hard and messy code".

Though this is the most important question I've ever asked here. 4 years later and I'm a much more mature programmer with jobs that pay.

Comment: @HolyRandom well you basically asked how to store polymorphic objects. `std::variant` allows to decouple the types (avoid inheritance) yet still have them in a single collection. Also, you basically benefit from static polymorphism since you know all the types at compile time.  However, given the premise of *"different elements sharing the same principle"* I would suggest to use an ECS instead and store a vector of Components. It is more cache friendly.

Comment: @HolyRandom also, "4 years later" I would not suggest to use a switch statement like in my answer (maybe I'll update it), but a dispacth with `std::visit` using function overloading